# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS black screen after boot

Tags: 14.04

Yesterday, Ubuntu system of my father's notebook  doesn't boot  properly, ( black screen). Thanks to a dual boot (Windows7 / ubuntu 14.04) Win7 started. So I looked at var/log /boot.log; but there are no errors.
Here's a log:

```
   * Starting Mount filesystems on boot[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Initialize or finalize resolvconf[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Track if upstart is running in a container[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge udev events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that remote filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting device node and kernel event manager[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting load modules from /etc/modules[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that the rootfs is mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping load modules from /etc/modules[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Clean /tmp directory[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Clean /tmp directory[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that local filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount filesystems on boot[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting flush early job output to logs[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting D-Bus system message bus[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping flush early job output to logs[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting system logging daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting SystemD login management service[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Uncomplicated firewall[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting bluetooth daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Read required files in advance[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make sure remote queues are populated[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make sure remote queues are populated[74G[[31mfail[39;49m]
 * Starting Bridge file events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting SMB/CIFS File Server[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Failsafe Boot Delay[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting modem connection manager[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting network connection manager[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server[74G[[31mfail[39;49m]
 * Starting CUPS printing spooler/server[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Samba Auto-reload Integration[74G[ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
 * Starting cups-browsed - Bonjour remote printer browsing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Samba Auto-reload Integration[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting set console font[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping set console font[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting userspace bootsplash[74G[ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting Send an event to indicate plymouth is up[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge socket events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting configure virtual network devices[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping userspace bootsplash[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting AppArmor profiles       [160G 
[154G[ OK ]
 * Setting up X socket directories...       [160G 
[154G[ OK ]
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Restore Sound Card State[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting anac(h)ronistic cron[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting ACPI daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting crash report submission daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Restore Sound Card State[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Restore Sound Card State[74G[ OK ]
```

Where else should I search for? **I do it remotely, using Teamviewer**, so I have no possibility to run console commands.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, no free space on ubuntu partition left. So after I deleted couple of files the system boots. I have deleted them remotely using Teamviewer from Windows 7.